# bsCollapsePanel's name duplicated when using conditionalPanel

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to keep `bsCollapse` and `tabsetPanel` open the same, at first it worked fine, but when I introduce the `conditionalPanel`, vector `open_panel` duplicates the name of the panel, which prevents the corresponding tab from opening!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

shinyApp(
  ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        bsCollapse(id = "panels",
          bsCollapsePanel("A",
            "This is panel A",
            selectInput("select", "select", choices = c(0, 1, 2, 3)),
            conditionalPanel(condition = "input.select != 0",
              selectInput("select_update", "select_update", choices = NULL)
            )
          ),
          bsCollapsePanel("B", "This is panel B"),
          bsCollapsePanel("C", "This is panel C"),
          bsCollapsePanel("D", "This is panel D")
        )
      ),
      mainPanel(
        verbatimTextOutput("panel_opened"),
        tabsetPanel(id = "tabs",
          tabPanel("A", "This is tab A"),
          tabPanel("B", "This is tab B"),
          tabPanel("C", "This is tab C"),
          tabPanel("D", "This is tab D"),
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  server <- function(session, input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$panels, {
        open_panel <- input$panels
        output$panel_opened <- renderPrint({print(open_panel)})
        updateTabsetPanel(session, "tabs", selected = open_panel)
    })
    observeEvent(input$tabs, {
      selected_tab <- input$tabs
      updateCollapse(session, "panels", open = selected_tab)
    })
    observeEvent(input$select, {
      if (input$select == 1) {
        updateSelectInput(session, "select_update", choices = c(10, 100, 1000))
      } else if (input$select == 2) {
        updateSelectInput(session, "select_update", choices = c(20, 200, 2000))
      } else if (input$select == 3) {
        updateSelectInput(session, "select_update", choices = c(30, 300, 3000))
      }
    })
  }
)
```

In this case, I have found a solution for myself, although I can't make that input correct, I can still read the value I want via `tail()`

```
open_panel <- tail(input$panels, 1)
```

Comment: Panel name is getting duplicated but I can open the tab as well.

Comment: This seems like a bug and was already asked here: [Conflict between shinyBS::bsCollapse and shiny::conditionalPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58015021/conflict-between-shinybsbscollapse-and-shinyconditionalpanel).